# Spring Boot Named Injection affects default Bean

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I was working with MongoDB configurations in SpringBoot. I was using mongo connection URI to use SpringBoot's auto-configuration.

I also wanted to create a secondary bean for MongoClient. Created it like `@Bean(name = "secondaryMongoClient")`. This is the only bean I created manually. But I noticed that the property changes inside this named injection also affected the default MongoClient bean. Because of this, I had to manually create another bean.

Is this SpringBoot's expected behavior? If yes, is there any workaround to avoid creating two beans and get the work done with single MongoClient secondary bean creation?

This seems to be a general behavior for any kind of Bean in SpringBoot but as I encountered it while working with MongoClient, thought it'll be better to pose in that context.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with Spring with Mongo, but  you also define the connection properties in your `properties.application` or `.yaml` file, right? If that's the case, I believe you can set your secondary bean there, or you can define your primary bean in Java, annotate it with `@Primary` and naming it, and use your current secondary Bean code.

Comment: What is your purpose in creating 2 beans of the same thing? Spring works with singletons. If you create a Bean manually, Spring normally grabs it. If your secondary bean connects to different datasource, take a look [Multiple Databases](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-multiple-databases)